# How to check for NS_AVAILABLE_IOS with const CGFloat

Tags: ios, objective-c

When a method can only be used on certain iOS versions, I usually check for its availability using `respondsToSelector:`.

With a `const CGFloat` declaration this is not possible.

The specific constant I'm trying to use is `UIFontWeightBlack` which is defined as:

```
UIKIT_EXTERN const CGFloat UIFontWeightBlack NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_2);
```

What is the best way to check if the iOS version my code is running in supports this constant?

---

Also if I want to support building my framework with older versions of the iOS SDK, what is the best way to check at compile time, if the used SDK offers this symbol?

I would currently do the check with

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_8_2
```

Is there a way to check for the symbol directly, without having to rely on / explicitly specify the iOS SDK version?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is covered in the [SDK Compatibility Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000163i).

> Check the availability of an external (extern) constant or a notification name by explicitly comparing its address—and not the symbol’s bare name—to NULL or nil.

So your code would be:

```
if (&UIFontWeightBlack != NULL) {
    // It is safe to use the constant
}
```

Comment: The second part of my question is covered in the [Conditionally Compiling for Different SDKs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002000-1114741-CJADDEIB) section. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Oops. I didn't even notice you had a two-part question. I just answered the first half.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the second part of your question, change your compile time check to the following:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 80200 // 80200 is the value of __IPHONE_8_2
```

We want to fall back to use the value of the macro rather than the macro itself as the macro is not defined in older versions of the iOS SDK.

As you mentioned in a comment, this is covered in the [Conditionally Compiling for Different SDKs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002000-1114741-CJADDEIB) section:

> The following code excerpt demonstrates this. Notice the use of the
>   numerical value `1050` instead of the symbol `__MAC_10_5` in the `#if`
>   comparison clause: If the code is loaded on an older system that does
>   not include the symbol definition, the comparison still works.

Comment: Wow ... completely overlooked that 

Comment: No worries, happens to the best of us. ;)